# <a> element messed up with https urls

Tags: php, html

I have a simple `<a>` element in my website:
`href="//<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank">LINK`

The `$link` is retrieved off my database.
This `$link` is like: `google.com, www.google.com, https://google.com, http://google.com`.

I have read that, in order to have absolute `href` urls, I should prefix the `$url` with `//`.
But when `$link=https://www.google.com` The `<a>` element redirects the browser to `https://https//www.fxp.co.il` - which is wrong. How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can create a simple function like this:

```
<a href="<?= getClearUrl($link); ?>" target="_blank">LINK</a>
```

the function:

```
function getClearUrl($link){
    if(filter_var($link, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
        return $link;
    }else{
        return "//" . $link;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$link` already contains the `https://` or `http://` (or `//`) at the start, then you should not prefix it with another `//`, but if it doesn't the you should, so maybe check for that before echoing the link.